# use PDL::Constants without "Subroutine redefined"

Tags: perl, pdl

To be able to use the constant `PI` of Perl Data Language, I run with `perl -w` the lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDL::Constants qw( PI );
```

However, Perl warns me:

> Subroutine PDL::Constants::piddle redefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/PDL/Constants.pm line 29.
>   Subroutine PDL::Constants::null redefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/PDL/Constants.pm line 29.
>   Subroutine PDL::Constants::pdl redefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/PDL/Constants.pm line 29.
>   Subroutine PDL::Constants::barf redefined at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/PDL/Constants.pm line 29.

The same warning arises, if I run the synopsis from https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Constants#PI

```
use PDL::Constants qw(PI E);
print 'PI is ' . PI . "\n";
print 'E  is ' .  E . "\n";
```

What is the correct way to import PI and others of PDL's constant values?

Comment: I works fine here (Ubuntu 19.10, perl version 5.30). I get no warnings, what operating system are you using?

Comment: What version of PDL are you using? I am using version 2.020: `perl -MPDL -E 'say $PDL::VERSION'`

Comment: Can't replicate with latest version. Looked at the code. The line numbers from the error message correspond to a blank link in the source of the latest version. Start by upgrading.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland here, it is 2.019. So that could be the reason indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this in latest PDL:

`perl -w -Mblib -MPDL::Constants -e 1`

produces no warnings.